# Problem connecting to L2TP VPN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn

I installed `l2tp-ipsec-vpn‍‍` from `ppa:werner-jaeger/ppa-werner-vpn`.
Yesterday I was able to connect to my L2TP vpn account successfully.
But after restart i'm getting this on `syslog`:

```
Mar 07 21:16:44.834 xl2tpd[7179]: death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received
Mar 07 21:16:44.835 Stopping xl2tpd: xl2tpd.
Mar 07 21:16:44.866 recvref[22]: Protocol not available
Mar 07 21:16:44.867 xl2tpd[7225]: This binary does not support kernel L2TP.
Mar 07 21:16:44.867 Starting xl2tpd: xl2tpd.
Mar 07 21:16:44.868 xl2tpd[7226]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.2.8 started on my-laptop PID:7226
Mar 07 21:16:44.868 xl2tpd[7226]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Mar 07 21:16:44.868 xl2tpd[7226]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Mar 07 21:16:44.868 xl2tpd[7226]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Mar 07 21:16:44.868 xl2tpd[7226]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006
Mar 07 21:16:44.869 xl2tpd[7226]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701
Mar 07 21:16:45.898 xl2tpd[7226]: Connecting to host vp3.nasaserver.org, port 1701
Mar 07 21:16:50.903 xl2tpd[7226]: Maximum retries exceeded for tunnel 39372.  Closing.
```

I'm using Ubuntu Lucid Lynx.
What is the problem?

Comment: Why didn't you use Ubuntu's package?

Comment: @vonbrand: I followed ths: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100039/l2tp-vpn-connection-plugin , I don't think it be package's problem; is it?